# PhoneGap 1.8 BlackBerry - Failed to find feature with id: org.apache.cordova

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I'm building on OSX 10.7 with ant. I've check I have good version of JAVA (1.6.0), etc. I can't seem to run the sample for PhoneGap 1.8 or 1.7. Here is the output from the terminal after I type **ant blackberry build**:

```
Buildfile: /Users/me/blackberry 1.8/sample/build.xml

blackberry:
build:
generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: CordovaSample.cod
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/me/blackberry 1.8/sample/build
package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/me/blackberry 1.8/sample/build/widget
     [copy] Copying 8 files to /Users/me/blackberry 1.8/sample/build/widget
      [zip] Building zip: /Users/me/blackberry 1.8/sample/build/CordovaSample.zip
build:
     [exec] [INFO]    Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]    Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [WARN]    Build ID set in config.xml [version], but signing key file was not found: author.p12
     [exec] [WARN]    Build ID set in config.xml [version], but no signing password was provided [-g]. Bar will be unsigned
     [exec] [INFO]    Generating output files
     [exec] [ERROR]   Failed to find feature with id: org.apache.cordova
```

I have put the right link to the bbwp file in the BlackBerry webworks SDK (10) which I downloaded and installed. I put that in **project.properties** like so.

```
blackberry.bbwp.dir=/rim
```

I still get the error: **Failed to find feature with id: org.apache.cordova**

**ANSWER:** I found a solution. I installed an older version of BlackBerry webworks (2.3). You can find older versions here: [Older webworks versions](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/previousversions)

Comment: I found a solution. I installed an older version of BlackBerry webworks (2.3).

Comment: Using this webworks i have developed a helloworld application and i build and generated the cod file but when i try to deploy to real device  blackberry curve that is 8900 device I am getting error: "  the specified module was rejected  by the device", do u know  this webworks  only supports os version above 6?